# Add custom language to Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

At our company we have developed a own little language to make our product more flexible. It is like a script language and we wrote like an interpreter in C++. Currently we develop this language in Eclipse with a small dropin to index a FunctionHelp.sct in which every method is declared we have in this language.

My question is now, is this also possible in Visual studio?
I haven't found any solutions yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, certainly possible thru extension (VSIX). One (open source) example is Iron Python.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/extend/